# Move an entire Excel row down with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to successfully move 1 row up one row, without adding a row or deleting the upper row.

It is easy to read and write, unlike offset statements, and it works as planned. However when I change the "+1" to a "-1" to move a row down, it does not work. In fact it seems to do nothing, not even return an error.

These routines are for a form which edits line items on a worksheet from a command button. Any ideas on what is wrong...or how to make this work?

```
Rows(lngActiveRow).Cut

Rows(lngActiveRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

lngActiveRow = lngActiveRow + 1
```

I use the variable `lngActiveRow` to substitute `Activecell.Row` because I was told it is faster to access a variable than a worksheet property...Correct?

Comment: try Shift:=xlUP

Answer (score 1):

if you move up only one row, the row to be moved will be moved under the row above - so it is in the same place again. So you have to go 2 up.